# Session Not Being Held in Firefox, Safari, or Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, session, firefox, safari

EDIT: Using Incognito browsing in Chrome and the session is not holding there either.

When I try to use my PHP web application in Firefox/Safari/Chrome I can log in, but after a short period (usually 1 or 2 page requests) the website is asking me to log in again. I am not really sure where to begin on this and was looking to get some general troubleshooting guidance on how to go about diagnosing this problem. I've seen others with similar issues, but with a different combination of browsers (i.e. Firefox holding session, but Chrome not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check

```
session_set_cookie_params
```

and

```
session_cache_expire
```

Probably your firefox and safary won't accept the cookie being set for the session. There are different approaches for identifying clients, read the session part at php.net.

Comment: I just added to my question - with Firefox or Safari I can log in, but after a short period (usually 1 or 2 page requests) the website is asking me to log in again.

Comment: I looked into the cookie_params by checking php_info() and I realized I had set my session.cookie_lifetime to expire after a short period of time (30). Silly mistake - thanks for pointing me in the right direction.